# TensorFlow add large numbers

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow2.0

In my model, I get to add small numbers with some large numbers. But this produces an incorrect value. Here is a simplified example:

```
import tensorflow as tf
a = tf.Variable(-1.55786165e+14 ,dtype=np.float32)
b = tf.Variable(-112522840.,dtype=np.float32)
c = tf.Variable(-34. ,dtype=np.float32)

a+b+c
```

This gives `<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=-155786280000000.0>` where as the correct answer should be -155786277522874

How can i correct this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same behavior can be observed using `numpy` directly. However, this only appears when using `dtype=np.float32` rather than `dtype=np.float64`. Change your `dtype` to `np.float64` to correct the problem.

In order to understand why, you must understand how are floating point numbers stored in memory. Let us consider `a` when represented with single precision and with double precision:

```python
import numpy as np

a = -1.55786165e+14
a_single = np.array([a], dtype=np.float32)
a_double = np.array([a], dtype=np.float64)
a_single[0], a_double[0], a
# The line above prints:
# (-155786160000000.0, -155786165000000.0, -155786165000000.0)
```

As you can see, `a` is truncated when using single precision. But why is that?

The base-2 logarithm of `abs(a)` is between 47 and 48. Hence, `a` can be written as `-1 * 2^47 * 1.x`. When representing floating points number, one has to encode the exponent (48) and the fraction (x).

In our case, `.x` would be approximately equal to:

```python
-a / pow(2, 47) - 1
```

which is equal to `0.1069272787267437`. Now, what we want is writing this number as a sum of negative power of 2, starting from -1. This means that if we use `N` bits to represent it, we will store in memory the integer part of `0.1069272787267437 * pow(2, N)`.

In single precision, we use `N = 23` bits to represent this number. Since the integer part of `0.1069272787267437 * pow(2, 23)` is 896971, whose binary expansion is `11011010111111001011`, which is 20-bits long, the number stored in memory is `00011011010111111001011`.

When using double precision however, the number stored in memory is `0001101101011111100101100000110100101110100000000000`. Note that the large number of trailing zeroes may indicate that the exact value of `a` is stored (since we don't need more precision to represent it), which is the case here.

That said, this explains why `a` while represented as a single precision float is truncated. The same reasoning works for adding `b` to `a`. Since the exponent of the resulting float will be `47`, it means that the smallest possible precision you can claim in single precision is `2^47 * 2^-23=2^24`, while the smallest possible precision you can claim in double precision is `2^47 * 2^-52=2^-5`. Since you are working with integers, this explains why you get an exact result with double precision and an incorrect one with single precision.